# Problem with tree traversal method for n-ary tree

Tags: c++, tree, traversal, insertion

I have a **Tree** class with a private nested **Node** class. I am trying to write a traversal method and the problem is that I am only able to print out the first level of my tree. 
I am not sure if there is something wrong with mu traversal method. Because I don't see another way to write it. I think the problem comes from `ins` method which inserts a child in a specific index of a tree. I think I am inserting into different objects.

Thank you in advanced for your help

Comment: What does you debugger say?

Comment: @Evg Actually i just did a debug and I understand that the insertion method works fine, the problem is with traversal method but I don't understand what is the problem

Comment: @Evg but also when I do `n1.fils(0)->fils(0)->print();` I get a segmentation fault which is really bwierd. `n1.fils(0)->fils(0)->print();` thakes the first child of my root and then takes the first child of that child wich is **D** in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your insertion is broken. You first insert nodes `B` and `C` by copying them:

```
_info->getChildren()[index] = childTree;
```

and **only then** you insert nodes `D` and `E` into original trees `n1_1` and `n1_2`. The easiest way to somehow fix the error is to change the order of insertions:

```
n1_1.ins(0, n1_1_1);
n1_2.ins(0, n1_2_1);
n1.ins(0, n1_1);
n1.ins(1, n1_2);
```

Alternatively, you could insert nodes directly into the tree. That is, first get corresponding `Tree`, then insert into it. Keeping your syntax and assuming that some data members are public:

```
n1.ins(0, n1_1);
n1.ins(1, n1_2);

n1._info->_children[0].ins(0, n1_1_1);  // n1._info->_children[0]) is not n1_1
n1._info->_children[1].ins(1, n1_2_1);  // n1._info->_children[1]) is not n1_2
```

Your code has a lot of other issues to address. If you could rewrite it with `std::unique_ptr`s instead of raw pointers, you'll resolve many of them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer . I don't know exactly what i should change in order to write it with `std::unique_ptr`? Could you help me please?

Comment: Is there a way to avoid coping these trees and passed them by reference to `ins`? (At least that is what i thought I was doing but apparently I was doing it wrong)

Comment: @Mohammadreza, that's a lot of work and explanations. If you could manage that yourself, you'll be able to significantly improve your code and general understanding of the language.

Comment: Evg what if there was a way to passe the reference instead of coping the trees and insert into original trees instead of the copies?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to use `unique_ptr` and rewrite this code because direct insertion may not be a good idea because in that case i have to use public data members which is not a good idea

Comment: @Mohammadreza 1) Just write appropriate member functions to access them. Your method `n1.ins(0, n1_1);  n1_1.ins(...);` can be put to work by using e.g. `vector<Tree*>` for `children`, but this will mess things up, don't do it. Using `unique_ptr` alone will not allow you to go that way. 2) I don't see why you need a `Tree` class at all. `Node` is already a tree. Try to remove `Tree` and make some member functions like `inorderTraverse` just free ones, that take `Node*` parameter - `void inorderTraverse(Node*)`. This will simplify your code. 3) Don't use `char` for indexing, use `std::size_t`.

Comment: @Mohammadreza, 4) `std::vector` is a dynamic array, it knows its size, you don't need the `_size` member.